# Generate DES3_MAC using ncipher

Tags: java, macos, tripledes

I need to generate a triple DES mac in java (like ISO9797Alg3Mac in Bouncy Castle) by using nCipherKM provider because my key is in nCipher HSM and I can not export the key and use it by software provider like Bouncy Castle. And I can not find implementation of such mac in nCipherKM provider. 
Anyone has an idea...?

Thanks